# Unauthorized Request problem of an endpoint

Tags: javascript, html

Hello to all of my I am in question in the influence of JavaScript development, but I have a problem when questioning the API in the intention of deleting data from its ID. I created a token during authentication in the location and when deleting the data I refer to the token in the at the top of the request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sophie Bluel - Architecte d'intérieur</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syne:wght@700;800&family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">   
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Sophie Bluel <span>Architecte d'intérieur</span></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="nav_menu projects"><a href="#portfolio">projets</a></li>
                <li class="nav_menu contact"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
                <li class="nav_menu login"><a href="pages/login.html">login</a></li>
                <li class="nav_menu logout_hidden"><a href="index.html">logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="./assets/icons/instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="introduction">
            <figure>
                <img src="./assets/images/sophie-bluel.png" alt="">
            </figure>
            <article>
                <h2>Designer d'espace</h2>
                <p>Je raconte votre histoire, je valorise vos idées. Je vous accompagne de la conception à la livraison finale du chantier.</p>
                <p>Chaque projet sera étudié en commun, de façon à mettre en valeur les volumes, les matières et les couleurs dans le respect de l’esprit des lieux et le choix adapté des matériaux. Le suivi du chantier sera assuré dans le souci du détail, le respect du planning et du budget.</p>
                <p>En cas de besoin, une équipe pluridisciplinaire peut-être constituée : architecte DPLG, décorateur(trice)</p>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section id="portfolio">
            <div class="edit_project">
                <h2>Mes Projets</h2>
                <div class="popup_edit">
                    <a href="#modal1" class="js-modal modify_action modify_hidden"><i class="fa-xs fa-solid fa-edit"></i> modifier</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation">
                <a href="#" class="active nav_link tous">Tous</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav_link objets">Objets</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav_link appartements">Appartements</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav_link hotels_restaurants">Hôtels&restaurants</a>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="contact">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <p>Vous avez un projet ? Discutons-en !</p>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <label for="name">Nom</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Envoyer">
            </form>
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Mentions Légales</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>

    <aside id="modal1" class="modal" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="titlemodal" style="display:none;">
        <div class="modal-wrapper js-modal-stop">
            <div class="wrapper-nav">
                <a href="#" class="js-modal-close closed"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-content">
                <div class="content-title modal1-title">
                    <h2>Galerie photo</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal_gallery">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr><br>
            <div class="wrapper-link">
                <a href="pages/modal/modal2.html#modal2" class="js-modal modal_submit">Ajouter une photo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This js code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const listOfWorks = document.querySelector(".modal_gallery");
    const _works = fetch('http://localhost:5678/api/works')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('data', data);
            modalData(data);
        });

    async function modalData(data) {
        data.forEach((item, i) => {
            const sectionWorks = document.querySelector(".modal_gallery");
            const workElement = document.createElement("figure");
            workElement.classList.add('work-element');

            const imageElement = document.createElement("img");
            imageElement.src = item.imageUrl;
            imageElement.style.width = "76.86px";
            imageElement.style.height = "102.57px";

            const trashIcon = document.createElement("i");
            trashIcon.classList.add('fa-regular', 'fa-trash-can', 'trash-icon');

            const linkIcon = document.createElement("a");
            linkIcon.classList.add('link-icon');
            linkIcon.appendChild(trashIcon);

            linkIcon.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                deleteImage(item);
            });

            const figcaptionElement = document.createElement("figcaption");
            figcaptionElement.style.fontSize = "14px";

            sectionWorks.appendChild(workElement);
            workElement.appendChild(imageElement);
            workElement.appendChild(linkIcon);
            workElement.appendChild(figcaptionElement);
        });
        return sectionWorks
    }        
});

function deleteImage(item) {
    console.log('item: ', item);
    token = window.localStorage.getItem("token")
    console.log(token)
    fetch(`http://localhost:5678/api/works/${item.id}`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

This is the representation of the api
[image]

This is the error inside the log

[image]

I forget to put here code for login who show how I decide to store token in the localStorage

```
function ajoutListenerLogin() {
    const formulaireLogin = document.querySelector(".formulaire-login");
    formulaireLogin.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        // Désactivation du comportement par défaut du navigateur
        event.preventDefault();
        // Création de l’objet de connexion.
        const login = {
            email: event.target.querySelector("[name=email]").value,
            password: event.target.querySelector("[name=password]").value,
        };
        // Création de la charge utile au format JSON
        const chargeUtile = JSON.stringify(login); 
        console.log(chargeUtile)
        // Appel de la fonction fetch avec toutes les informations nécessaires
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5678/api/users/login/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: chargeUtile
        })
        .then(response => {
            if(response.status === 200) {
                window.location.href = "../index.html"; // Redirige vers la page d'accueil
                console.log(response.status)
                // Stockage des informations dans le localStorage
                if (window.localStorage.getItem("auth") === null){
                    window.localStorage.setItem("token", response.body)
                    window.localStorage.setItem("auth", chargeUtile);
                }else{
                    window.localStorage.clear();
                    window.localStorage.setItem("auth", chargeUtile);
                }    
            } else {
                console.log('Erreur de connexion');
            }
            const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
            if (contentType && contentType.includes('application/json')) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                console.log(response)
                throw new Error('La réponse du serveur n\'est pas un JSON valide');
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Erreur lors de la récupération des données :', error);
        });               
    });
}

ajoutListenerLogin()
```

Comment: Note that fetch will only error if it fails to successfully *communicate* with the server, the success branch will be taken even if the server rejects the request, which is why you're seeing "Success: { error: ...}" in the console. Check the statusCode of the response object.

Comment: 401 isn't a code error.  It's valid HTTP response.  Unauthorized.  It seems like you are not authorized to call the delete endpoint.  There may be some business logic in the 'Delete' operation that is blocking the delete.  Maybe you're not allowed to delete #9

Comment: Does the server allow DELETE (and PUT, OPTION) requests? It looks like the GET request is OK, so it is probably not a CORS issue (are both web and API on the same port nunber?).

Comment: Yeah chrwahl, it is the DELETE requests and the servers allow them

Comment: Have you tried accessing the DELETE Endpoint from Swagger?

Comment: yeah, that work correctly

Comment: It might be a silly question but are you certain that the token gets stored? The `window.location.href` is above all of the localStorage stuff so it might skip executing that stuff. You could also put a breakpoint in the `Authorization` method in your backend and see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the first part of the URL as follows:

```
fetch('/api/works')
```

Comment: that case doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

everyone, I Obtain answers of this question in an other platform, and this gave me a solution that work correctly:

```
function ajoutListenerLogin() {
    const formulaireLogin = document.querySelector(".formulaire-login");
    formulaireLogin.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        // Désactivation du comportement par défaut du navigateur
        event.preventDefault();
        // Création de l’objet de connexion.
        const login = {
            email: event.target.querySelector("[name=email]").value,
            password: event.target.querySelector("[name=password]").value,
        };
        // Création de la charge utile au format JSON
        const chargeUtile = JSON.stringify(login);
        console.log(chargeUtile)
        // Appel de la fonction fetch avec toutes les informations nécessaires
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5678/api/users/login/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: chargeUtile
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(data.token) {
                window.localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
                window.localStorage.setItem("auth", chargeUtile);
                window.location.href = "../index.html"; // Redirige vers la page d'accueil
            } else {
                console.log('Erreur de connexion');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Erreur lors de la récupération des données :', error);
        });
    });
}

ajoutListenerLogin();
```